# How to Adjust the Sidebar Width in the Lightning Console

Tags: lightning, console, lightning-console

In Salesforce Classic, the sidebar width can be adjusted by clicking and dragging on the boundary of the sidebar, but this does not work in Lighting. How can the sidebar width be adjusted in Lightning?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Salesforce Help Article "[What Features Are Available in Lightning Console Apps?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console_lex_feature_parity.htm&type=5)", a "Resizeable split view" is not available in Lighting. There is a Salesforce Idea, [Allow for Adjustable Width of Split View Sidebar in Lighting Console](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015A7FQAU), posted on the Trailblazer Community requesting this features be added.